# How to get back data entered in html controls on clicking of back button in browser in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am retain earlier values in web page controls once user click on back button in browser .

I want to do that in Angular application.

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific way to tell when a user presses the back button.

What you can do, is call an ngDestroy hook and set local Storage items in the hook, refer to this article on how to set local storage items:
https://medium.com/@tiagovalverde/how-to-save-your-app-state-in-localstorage-with-angular-ce3f49362e31